Adding Average at the very last part of the row and column in a dataset
I have a sample dataset of total outbound calls, it comprises rows (dates) and columns (hourly), my goal is to show totals and average of outbound calls per day (rows), and the totals and average of calls per hour (column). Now, I believe I dont have any problems showing the average of these data per columns and per rows, I can simply use =average function and select the entire row to get the day's average calls, and select the entire column to get the hour's average calls, but my problem is adding the average on the very last part, corner of the table (last row and last column). I wanted to get the average of the average hourly and the average of average per day, but I dont think I can be able to do that at the same time in the same cells (see yellow highligted cell in the screenshot). Is there a correct or standard way of doing this or showing the average on that corner of the table?


You want two averages and there are three cells highlighted, what is the problem?

If I put sum on cell O28 and sum the entire rows from cell B28:N28, it would show the same result if you sum the entire column O3:O27. Now, when I put average on cell O29, and wanted to get the average of the entire column O3:O27, how and where do I put another formula to get the average of the entire row from that cell (B29:N29) so I can also get the average of the hourly average from columns B to N.

You will need to join them: ="Daily Average - "&TEXT(AVERAGE(O3:O27),"0.00")&" | Hourly Average: "&TEXT(AVERAGE(B29:O29),"0.00")

You can also litteraly think outside the box and used a few extra cells below and/or to the right of the table (ex. P29 or O30)

Okay I got it! I was also just thinking if there is a correct or a standard way of representing the averages of a dataset. Thank you for all these suggestions!
